# Binomial vs z test vs t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Let's say in my population the mean number of pink balls is 8%, but I have a sample with 5 pink balls out of 23 balls (the other balls are white), ~22% pink.

I want to get a measure of how significant this is given the small sample size.

## Exact binomial

$$
n = 23\\
p = 0.08  \\
\mathbb{P}(\ge 5)=\sum_{k=5}^{23} {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$

Evaluating this in Python

```
from scipy.stats import binom
sum([binom.pmf(x, 23, 0.08) for x in range(5, 24)])
0.032622135514507766
```

Seems quite significant, just a 3% chance of getting 5 or more pinks.

## 1-sided z test using the CLT

I don't know my population mean, but maybe I could assume it is $\sigma=\sqrt{p(1-p)}=0.08(1-0.08)=0.0736$ if $X \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} \text{Ber}(p)$. Then

$$
q = \sqrt{n}\frac{(5/23)-0.08}{\sigma}
$$

Evaluating it in Python

```
from scipy.stats import norm
p = 0.08
sigma_true = np.sqrt(p*(1-p))  # assuming underlying distribution X was binomial
n = 23
q = np.sqrt(n)*((5/23)-p)/np.sqrt(sigma_true)
# 1-norm.cdf(q)+norm.cdf(-q)  # 2-sided
1 - norm.cdf(q)  # 1 sided
```

This gives `0.10292878018723539` or around 10%, so not significant if $\alpha=5%$.

I also tried a 1-sample t-test in Python (which is 2 sided so I divide by 2 to match the above z-test)

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp as ttest
sample = [1]*5 + [0]*18  # 1 is pink, 0 not pink
ttest(sample, 0.08).pvalue/2
```

which gives `0.06623889637034054` or around 6%

## Summary

Which of these analysis is correct and why? I'm aware my sample is too small for the z-test (which gave 10%) and the t-test is likely better, but is my binomial analysis even correct? 3% is quite different to the 6% of the t-test.

Bonus: how does the t-test "know" the population variance from a single sample? why does it not ask that as an input just like it asks for population mean?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the structure of your question.  You say that you KNOW that the population proportion of pink balls is $p=0.22$.  Usually we don't know this parameter in advance, and hence the need for a sample.  Do you really have just a sample and you are wanting to test the hypothesis:  $H_0:p=0.23$ versus $H_1:p>0.23$?  Or do you actually know the population proportion?

Comment: No, $H_0: p=0.08, H_1: p> 0.08$

Comment: 1. What led you to do a one-tailed test? I worry because you didn't mention a directional hypothesis until after you mentioned the data.  2. How many balls are in the population?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the sample size $(n = 23)$ is less than 10% of the population size (all available balls), so that we can assume sampling is without replacement, the binomial test is exact. You are testing $H_0: p = 0.08$ against $H_a: p > 0.08.$ Under $H_0,$ the distribution of the number $X$ of
pink balls is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=23, p = 0.08),$ so the P-value of your one-sided test is $$P(X \ge 5) = 0.0326 < 0.05 = 5\%,$$ and you'd reject $H_0$ at the 5% level. [Computation in R where `pbinom` and `dbinom`
are, respectively, a binomial PDF and CDF.] This agrees with your computation.

```
1 - pbinom(4, 23, 0.08)
[1] 0.03262214
sum(dbinom(5:23, 23, 0.08))
[1] 0.03262214
```

Because, under $H_0,$ we have $E(X) = np = 23(0.08) = 1.54 < 5,$ it is not
reasonable to expect a good normal approximation to the null binomial distribution. Some people might use an approximate t distribution, but
I personally regard the basis of that to be more in terms of simulation than in terms of theory. So I think it is best to use the exact binomial test.

*Addendum:* Suppose your 'urn' has only $N = 100$ balls with eight pink and 92 non-pink, and sampling is without replacement.

Then under $H_0,$ the number $X$ of pink balls seen in $n=23$ draws is hypergeometric. Then the P-value for $X = 5$ pink balls is $0.0149,$ again leading to rejection of $H_0$ at the 5% level.

```
sum(dhyper(5:23, 8,92, 23))
[1] 0.01491856
```

However, if the urn has $N=1000$ balls, $80$ pink and the rest not, then the hypergeometric distribution is well approximated by binomial (P-value about $0.031$, as in the main part of this Answer):

```
sum(dhyper(5:23, 80,920,   23))
[1] 0.03089299
```

Comment: I guess I'm just surprised the t-test is so far off the exact result. Using that alone I was ready to not reject.

Comment: A reasonable alternative computation would be in case your 'urn' contains relatively few marbles so that the distinction between sampling with and without replacement may be important. See my addendum for $N=100$ balls in the urn of which $8$ are pink.